# Terminology and work on limited lifetime Ito processes

Tags: probability, reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am interested in ito processes (mostly ito diffusions) that "die" with some probability over time. E.g. A half life $\tau$ can be specified such that the expected lifetime of the process is $\tau$.

A special case I am interested in is where the probably of death is spatially (but not temporally) varying.

Specifically:

1. What are such processes called and what, if any, are some  interesting studies on them?
2. Is there some computationally efficient procedure for simulating these?

---

Edit (6/16/17): it seems like one idea is to consider random upper limits of integration i.e.
$$ X_t = \int_0^\tau \mu(X_s)ds + \int_0^\tau\sigma(X_s)ds $$
where $\tau$ is a random variable. This is obviously simple if $\tau$ is independent of $X_t$, but I am not sure what to do if I want to make it depend on the "history" of the process i.e. $\tau(X_s)$, so that if the process starts wandering in a particular area it is more likely to die early, for instance.

There does not seems to be much in the way of "random upper limits" for Ito processes (e.g. [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=FvQfYS4cJZQC&pg=PA177&lpg=PA177&dq=stochastic+integral+%22random+upper+limit%22&source=bl&ots=lbgZ9Zl7Ip&sig=0FIba58kXTVxAk54XFnOzEIPwBE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwik2PTDr8PUAhUn_4MKHcy5BncQ6AEIOTAF#v=onepage&q=stochastic%20integral%20%22random%20upper%20limit%22&f=false) and [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=UavVBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA105&lpg=PA105&dq=stochastic+ito+integral+%22random+upper+limit%22&source=bl&ots=l9zacyA3Yk&sig=WBwn3pxNlIE3SadT8hFaKJnbK6c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8ua6lscPUAhXjyoMKHbvTDBcQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=stochastic%20ito%20integral%20%22random%20upper%20limit%22&f=false) mention it).

Comment: Where is $t$ on the RHS  of your equation? What do you mean by "die"? (did you mean upper limit $t\wedge \tau$, so it holds at a constant value after $\tau$?)  It's pretty common to have a compound Poisson process where the rate is a drift-diffusion. You could consider the first jump 'death'.... these kinds of processes are sometimes used to model defaulting on loans.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks for your comment. I think you are right, in that the question is not that well defined. Your idea to use a Poisson process makes sense; it seems that I should define an intensity on the space $\lambda(X_t)$, so that the probability of a jump (which would stop the process here) changes depending on the path of $X_t$. Do you have references to recommend that are perhaps a bit on the computational side?

Comment: I don't have a particular reference... but you do see processes like this in finance: google 'stochastic jump rate' or stochastic default rate' maybe with 'simulating'. The most straightforward way to simulate would be to do a diffusion and flip a weighted coin each time step.